# Not able to see overlayfs usage by docker

Tags: docker

I have a CentOS where docker gives me info about the overlayFS usage.

```
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
[root@localhost ~]# df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       8.0G  3.5G  4.6G  44% /
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  180M  3.7G   5% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           781M     0  781M   0% /run/user/0
overlay         8.0G  3.5G  4.6G  44% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/194002afa67fa97156e5b690a21072df02b436f1fec2bb85e8a3929f7a62afe6/merged
overlay         8.0G  3.5G  4.6G  44% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c44da3222afacb8d289abf656862a396d5676b04f3f491fdf1b5b9a03908c2d9/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/77a3eb464031c7bdc35949c2192898f0700e183b6f962cdfb09f4de1334a66e7/mounts/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6e934813aba4889ea853adbb04c7b2a621a4283eb4fca5a074983bf264127c96/mounts/shm
```

But on my Ubuntu Laptop, I am not able to see how much is the overlay using. How else can I find it?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  2.3M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  938G  440G  450G  50% /
tmpfs            32G  1.2G   31G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      194M  194M     0 100% /snap/firefox/107
/dev/loop3      195M  195M     0 100% /snap/firefox/118
/dev/loop4      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/tmux/11
/dev/loop5       99M   99M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/270
/dev/loop6       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/loop8       35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop9       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop10      99M   99M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/266
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/loop11      88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop7       99M   99M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/274
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /tmp/isomount
tmpfs           6.3G   24K  6.3G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           6.3G  112K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop12     195M  195M     0 100% /snap/firefox/124
```

Answer (score 0):

The [overlay storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#how-the-overlay-driver-works) combines files in ordinary directories under `/var/lib/docker` to form the per-container filesystems; it doesn't have any particular space allocation of its own.  You should be able to use the entire available root filesystem disk space (unless you've mounted something else as `/var` or `/var/lib/docker`).  (Even in your CentOS example where it's listed explicitly, notice that the "overlay" usage is identical to the root file system usage.)